# Perform Simple Group By in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have the simplest query on google big query that keeps returning an error

`Grouping by expressions of type STRUCT is not allowed`

i am simply trying to select a list of emails from two locations, union them in one cte,  and count frequency in the cte to identify duplicates.

this should be very easy - what am i missing??

```
with a as (select properties.email as email, 'loc1' as tag from `loc1.contacts`),

b as (select properties.email as email, 'loc2' as tag from `loc2.contacts`),

c as (
select * from a 
union all
select * from b
)

select email, count(email) from c group by 1
```

```
sample data:

email/tag
bob@email.com/loc1
bob@email.com/loc2

expected results:
email/count
bob@email.com/2
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: done - its the simplest group by i could ever think of - just a simple count of how many times the email appears in the cte. i have to be missing some type of simple bigquery specific syntax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looks like i needed to add .value to actually get the value of the email field, following query worked as desired

```
with a as (select properties.email.value as email, 'loc1' as tag from `loc1.contacts`),

b as (select properties.email.value as email, 'loc2' as tag from `loc2.contacts`),

c as (
select * from a 
union all
select * from b
)

select email, count(email) from c group by 1
```